# how to make R studio work on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: lenovo, freeze, crash, 22.04, rstudio

[Rstudio freezing on opening after updating to ubuntu 22.04 ( i even had to use the xkill cammande to exit )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCK7q.png)

Answer (score 2):

Open it from terminal with command: "rstudio --no-sandbox". A fix is supposed to come out later this summer.

Comment: How do you know that a fix is planned? Can I track this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit rstudio.desktop to make clicking the Rstudio icon work as well.

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop`

Add `--no-sandbox` in the Exec-line